# Is it possible to use instrument to capture screen of a site from mobile safari?

Tags: iphone, xcode, instruments

UIASCRIPT:

```
var result = UIATarget.localTarget().host().performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout("/usr/bin/open", ["/Applications/Safari.app", "http://www.google.com"], 30);
UIATarget.captureScreenWithName('test.png');
```

command line:

```
instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate Safari.app -e UIASCRIPT cap.js
```

what's wrong with my approach? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you called captureScreenWithName method on UIATarget class instead of target object.

It should be:

`UIATarget.localTarget().captureScreenWithName('test.png');`

Note: Same for captureRectWithName.